# css remove extra space with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using [Slider Revolution Responsive jQuery Plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-jquery-plugin/2580848) on my website along with twitter bootstrap 3.0 . 
However there is a space on the right hand side which I am unable to remove. Please see the attached image.[image]

I have tried setting the margin to 0 as well but it is not working .

```
.tp-banner-container .tp-banner .tp-banner > ul .tp-banner > ul > li .tp-banner > ul > li >img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

The bootstrap and the slider are as follows
[image]

**Update 1**
The html page is here : http://pastebin.com/c5JPDPhT
while the css is here : http://pastebin.com/HAVKdxUj

**Update 2**
I have also uploaded a video on youtube that shows where the problem is. 
here is the link : http://youtu.be/KqqrXkEvzbI

Can someone please point out what am I missing ? 
thanks

Comment: I have tried almost everything but nothing is working.

Comment: You're only removing the margin from a very specific item - the innermost nested image.  There could be a margin or padding on an li, ul, tp-batter, or tp-banner-container.  Without being able to see a live version of the site, or knowing more about the css, it's hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: @PhillipKregg I have added the location where you can see the html and css code.

Comment: I took everything you posted and put it into a jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/phillipkregg/5f2AS/.  I'm not seeing a margin on the right side.  Perhaps it's something on the plugin you are using?

Comment: This is getting crazier as time goes by. When I am launching the chrome debugger tool , the white space disappears and everything is getting rendenered properly, while the space reappears as i close the developer tool

Comment: @PhillipKregg I have uploaded a video on youtube that shows the problem : http://youtu.be/KqqrXkEvzbI

Comment: Your video is marked as private, so no one can see it.  The chrome debugger tool will sometimes behave that way - you may want to make sure it is unattached from the page you are working on, sometimes that will help.

Comment: If you have any widths or anything affecting styling set in javascript, you may want to remove that as well - for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: Hmm.. i tried doing that - but then the the slider plugin fails (it does not render properly) . BTW.. i just uploaded everything to www. you can access the page here : http://www.softkrafts.com/granite/granite/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have a specific width that is being set on the tp-banner-container.

You can see it here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3DLj.png
[image]

This is probably being controlled by an attribute set in the JQuery plugin that you are using.  You can try to find it there and remove it, or override it with css.

If you set the width to 100% in css this fixes it as you can see:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZYBt.png
[image]

As a quick fix, if you *always* want tp-banner-container to be 100%, you could override the inline style that is being created with `width: 100% !important` inside your stylesheet.

Comment: the last part nailed it. as i had said earlier i was already using the width:100% but I was not marking it as !important. thanks Phillip . much appreciated. This is the correct answer to my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a link with the online page working?

Try this css code:

```
.tp-banner-container .tp-banner img{
     width: 100%;
}
```

and .tp-banner-container with width 100% too and position: relative.

Good Luck.

Comment: Nope - it does not work. i have shared the code where you can see/download the HTML and css